# How to optimize a bulk sql update on 25M rows

Tags: mysql, performance

I have the following query that i need to run to update a table with about ~25M rows.

```
UPDATE cast_info SET movie_url = 
    (SELECT imdb_id FROM title WHERE title.id = cast_info.movie_id)
```

Are there any things or variables I need to change in mysql before running this query, so instead of say taking ten hours, it only takes eight?

Comment: What % of the 25M rows have an **imdb_id** that is different from the previous value?  I ask this because the UPDATE logic optimizes out no-change updates.  In this case executing the inner join as per @MMadhivanan's suggestion will dominate time and the indexing here will be critical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE cast_info as ci inner join title as ti on ti.id = ci.movie_id
SET ci.movie_url =t.imdb_id
```